# Please welcome your moderators pro tempore

Tags: discussion, moderation

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that every community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: HDE 226868]
[image: Logan Maingi]
[image: Danu]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them and appreciate the hard work and time they will contribute.

#### Did we overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are many members here who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. Our failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, moderators should elected by the community, and that's why we'll hold elections once the site graduates.

Most of all, it's important to be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: Not really sure if I should put this as a comment or an answer, but I just want to say that the community as a whole has been doing an awesome job of doing community moderation tasks and checking the review queues. I encourage everyone to keep it up!

Answer (score 5):

Welcomes may not be so necessary for three of our community's finest and well known members, but moderator diamond congratulations are definitely in order, along with many thanks for taking on the task.

I'm sure I speak for all when I say best of luck in your duties. The three of you are going to serve us well in the future just as you have served our group so well in the past.

Congratulations, many thanks, and best of luck in your adventures.

Long Live HSM!

Comment: For I moment I was wondering what High School Musical had to do with anything! :P

Comment: @x-x I did not watch the movie, but I assume some humorous relation exists here. :))